# Retrofit Singleton Instance causing a 403 Issue in API calls?

Tags: java, retrofit, retrofit2

I have setup a retrofit2 singleton instance which is accessed by all API methods. However, upon logging out the user and re-signing in, all API calls fail with a 403. The likely cause of this is retrofit re-using the previous destroyed access token and not resetting the retrofit instance.

**Singleton:**

```
public class RetroGenerator {

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    private static Retrofit.Builder builder;
    public static Retrofit retrofit;

    static synchronized private Retrofit.Builder getBuilder() {

        if (builder == null) {
            initRetrofit();
        }
        return builder;
    }

    public static void initRetrofit() {
        builder =
                new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(SessionManager.getInstance().baseUrl)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(initGson()));
    }

    private static Gson initGson() {
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").create();
    }

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        return getBuilder().client(httpClient.build()).build();
    }

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return getRetrofit().create(serviceClass);
    }

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, final Auth auth) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            if (auth != null) {

                //Adding request payload logging
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
                    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
                    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
                }

                httpClient.retryOnConnectionFailure(true);
                httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request original = chain.request();
                        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                                .header("Authorization",
                                        auth.token_type + " " + auth.access_token)
                                .method(original.method(), original.body());
                        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                        return chain.proceed(request);
                    }
                });
            }

            OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();

            if (retrofit == null) {
                retrofit = getBuilder().client(client).build();
            }
        }

        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }

    public static void clearRetrofit(){
        retrofit = null;
    }
}
```

An API class would use this by:

```
RetroGenerator.createService(APIServices.class).getUsers().enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<User>> () {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call <ArrayList<User>> call, Response <ArrayList<User>> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            callBack.onSuccess(response.body());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call <ArrayList<User>> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

To amend this, my attempt was to set the retrofit instance as null upon signing out. Thus, the use of `clearRetrofit()` method. However, the issue still exists and setting it null didn't fix the issue. What is the reoolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. Here's the write-up:

**Problem:**

- I needed global access to a retrofit instance without having to re-initialise an instance every time
- The code in the question was confusing the public retrofit instance with authenticated endpoints thus leading to a 401: Unauthorised error.

**Solution:**

The solution I've attached below was written to deliver the following:
- Re-usability of a retrofit instance by using a Singleton design pattern

- Ability to write an interface `APIServices` and include all endpoints in it. This allows extensibility.
- Ability to switch between a retrofit built for public endpoints and a retrofit built for authenticated endpoints.

Here's my solution:
https://gist.github.com/dinukapj/b315e5f4438bc670d7509f7aa7aaffdd